# why confidence band does not cover the last points in geom_point plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, loess

I have a chart drawn by geom_point using the code below. Is it normal that the confidence band does not cover the entire chart? I am using `loess` method:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=Year_Month, y=CNT, group=1)) +
  geom_line(stat="identity", size=2, alpha=0.7, color="#00a9ff") +
  geom_point(size=5, color="#2787db") +
  geom_smooth(method = 'loess', color="red") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,mx,5), limits = c(-2,mx)) +
  geom_text(label=data$CNT, vjust=-2, color="blue")
```

**Chart:**
[image]

**sample of my data:**
[image]

Comment: It's possible you cut the ribbon off because of the limits on your y axis.  Check by removing `limits` from `scale_y_continuous()`.

Comment: Please share data in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Pictures of data are not helpful. What if you take out the `scale_y_continuous` line?

Comment: yes, the problem is `scale_y_continuous`, but how can I manually control my y scale if this causes a problem for me?

Comment: ok, the problem was -2 in the `scale_y_continuous`, I changed it to -5 and this way it covers the band entirely, thanks guys!